# Filtering an array of objects by an object property within an object within the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I'm in a nested hell of objects, here.  I feel like there's an answer to this, I just can't quite figure out how to phrase what's happening.

So, I get this giant array of objects from a REST return (something like 450+ objects) that comes loaded like this:

```
results[0] = {  
prop0: "String",  
prop1: "String",  
prop2: bool,  
prop3: Object {  
    prop0: "String"  
}
prop4: "String"  
}
```

I'm doing this thing, first, where I'm creating an array of objects that contains just the unique strings out of that nested object's property, along with a count of the number of times that string appears within the data set.

I now need, for each unique string, to create an array of objects within the original dataset where results.prop3.prop0 matches the string in the collapsed array.  Was that confusing enough?

From this:

Name: "Joe",
Place: state {
state: "New York",
},
Alive: false
}

To this:

**New York (120)**
Joe - Dead

I've gotten this far, using underscore.js:

```
for(index in collapsed){  
var details = _.where(results,{state: {state: collapsed[index][0]}});

console.log(details);

}
```

But I'm clearly an idiot somewhere, because that's just returning an empty array for each thing in my collapsed array.

**Sample of collapsed**
[{"New York",120},{"Georgia",79},{"Another Place",15}].

I basically want to build a table of data where, underneath each place, I load in the objects where Place matches the state string all the way at the bottom of the nested object.

To jm_____'s point, I'm going to try that.

Comment: Can you include a sample of what collapsed looks like? And is it `result[i].Place.state.state`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are examples of data manipulation with underscore based on `_.reduce()` and `_.filter()`

Getting collapsed array with number of items grouped by states

```
var collapsed = _.reduce(response, function(memo, item) {
  if ( ! memo[item.Place.state]) {
    memo[item.Place.state] = 0;
  }
  memo[item.Place.state]++;
  return memo;
}, {});
```

Result: grouped object with states as keys and count as values.

```
{
  London: 2,
  New York: 4
}
```

Getting filtered data by state

```
var filtered = _.filter(response, function(item) {
  return item.Place.state === "New York";
});
```

Result: array of objects with only state New York

Link to [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/gabufohipa/edit?js,console) demo

Comment: This definitely works.  I think I wanted to try and be clever and use the keys in the collapsed array as the filter text on the array of objects created by the json response.  I realize, now, that without a way to dynamically create a different array for each value in the collapsed array, the solution was unfeasible.  Thankfully, in the actual solution, the collapsed array will always have the same values so I can just hard code that in.